# Preparing a string for HMAC

Tags: python, node.js, hmac

I am writing a webservice which uses HMAC for message authentication.  I am having some issues preparing the 'data' for digest, and am getting different digests for the same 'data' in Python vs NodeJS.

I am fairly sure that this issue is due to encoding, but I am not sure how to best approach this.

Python code:

```
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1

f = open('../test.txt')
raw = f.read()

raw = raw.strip()

hm = hmac.new('12345', raw, sha1)
res = hm.hexdigest()
print res

>> 5bff447a0fb82f3e7572d9fde362494f1ee2c25b
```

NodeJS (coffee) code:

```
fs = require 'fs'
http = require 'http'
{argv} = require 'optimist'
crypto = require 'crypto'

# Load the file
file = fs.readFileSync argv.file, 'utf-8'
file = file.trim()

# Create the signature
hash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', '12345').update(file).digest('hex')
console.log(hash)

>> a698f82ea8ff3c4e9ffe0670be2707c104d933aa
```

Edit:  Also, the length of raw is 2 characters longer than file, but I cant work out where these two characters come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem with encoding of the data you read from the filesystem and has nothing with algorithms you use.

When you work with string data both in Python and JavaScript, you should be very careful about encoding which your data is stored in. Try to work with data either as with strings (which, in particular have such a property as encoding), or as with "raw data". When reading and signing data, you shouldn't probably care about the encoding, and try to use data as "raw" as much as you can in your language.

Some points to note:

- Filesystem stores "raw" bytes, and knows nothing about the contents and the encoding of your file. Furthermore, for some files (like, jpegs, for example), the "encoding" concept is worthless
- The same is valid for crypto algorithms. They work with raw bytes and know nothing about its "character representation". That's why digital signatures work so well with all sorts of binary documents, etc.
- `trim()` in javascript or `strip()` in python work with strings, and their behaviour can vary depending on the underlying encoding (try `u's '.encode('utf-16').strip().decode('utf-16')` in python, for example). If possible, I'd rather avoid using trimming, to not to mix the way you work with data.
- Python 2.x (and, I suppose, Javascript too) have set of rules for implicit conversion between strings and raw data.

Here in your code you work with binary data in Python, but do conversion to string in JavaScript, when you define the encoding of the file to read. Apparently, there is a sort of implicit converting from utf-8 back to raw string in crypto module, but I don't know what it does.

As described in [here](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer), the most kosher way of handing raw strings in node.js is to use buffers. You could read buffer from filesystem, but unfortunately, nodejs crypto library doesn't support them yet. As described [here](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_proposed_api_changes_in_future_versions_of_node):

> The Crypto module was added to Node before there was the concept of a
>   unified Stream API, and before there were Buffer objects for handling
>   binary data.
>
> As such, the streaming classes don't have the typical methods found on
>   other Node classes, and many methods accept and return Binary-encoded
>   strings by default rather than Buffers.

That's said, to make the example work, current approach is to read data by passing "binary" as the second argument to the call:

```
file = fs.readFileSync argv.file, "binary"
```

Also, as I said, I'd rather avoid stripping data I just read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas to try:

- Check that `raw` has the same length as `file`
- Open `f` as binary
- `import codecs` and use `codecs.open` with an encoding
- `strip` will remove all whitespace from start and end of a string in Python - I think `trim` only removes from the end. So you may want `rstrip()` possibly with explicit characters set to get the same behaviour

Comment: trim removes from start and end as well

Comment: you could be on to something, the lengths are different by 2 characters.  This is NOT do to with strip/trim, the different is 2 characters with out without them

Comment: @mrwooster Just narrows it down to if the same file is being read, then it's probably the encoding - happy hunting...

Comment: I think actually its down to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark thanks for your help